# Angular async routing function outside ngZone

Tags: angular, rxjs

The routing function was called in a **service**. I'm getting this warning:

```
Navigation triggered outside Angular zone, did you forget to call 'ngZone.run()'?
```

**However I can not call `this.ngZone.run(...)` because I need the event when the routing was completed.** By default `ngZone.run() => void` does not return any value.

The function looks like this:

```
private handleRedirectRouting(): Observable<boolean> {
   return this.route.queryParamMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params) => {
         if (params.get('_redirect')) {
            const route = params.get('_redirect');
            return from(this.router.navigate([route]));
         } else if (this.router.url.includes('auth/login')) {
            const route = '/';
            return from(this.router.navigate([route]));
         }
         return of(true);
      })
   );
}
```

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngZone.run()` is the right thing here since it can return a promise.

```
from(this.ngZone.run(() => {
   return this.router.navigate([route]));
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the code error by explicitly passing the return type of the function call:

```
this.ngZone.run<Observable<boolean>>(() => {
   return from(this.router.navigate([route]));
})
```